# JavaScript - XMLHttpRequest readystate = 1 && status = 0

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to access data from league of legends (riot api) and I keep getting 1 and 0 for the readystate and status respectively. Furthemore, I do not know if there are any restrictions on the api or if this is the right way of trying to access it(do I need to parse it?). I've taken the actual key out and summonerName but the concept is still there. Again I'm fairly new to this XMLHttpRequest method but here is my code:

```
var summoner = new XMLHttpRequest();
    summoner.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(summoner.readyState == 4 && summoner.status == 200) {
        console.log(summoner.responseText);
      }
    };
    summoner.open('GET', 'https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/summonerName?api_key=key');
    summoner.send();

    // var payload = JSON.parse(summoner.responseText);
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
 var username=$('#username').val();
            var xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
                    data=this.responseText;
                    alert(data);
                }
                if(this.status==404){
                    alert('404 Error Occured.');
                }
            }
            xmlHttp.open('get', 'checkusername.php?name=' + username, true);
            xmlHttp.onprogress=function(){
                console.log('Loading');
            }
            xmlHttp.send();
```

Comment: It's helpful to walk through the answer and explain how this code fixes the problem, so that the asker can learn and this post will be useful for others as well.